# Where to put custom .bashrc stuff, in .bash_local?

Tags: bash, bashrc

Just upgraded to 11.10, and prompted me to wondering where is now the preferred way to put customised `.bashrc` bits?

I have some aliases, some env variables, and a python virtualenvwrapper script, for instance, which I want to run as part of my `.bashrc`.  I have these synced in a script across machines stored in Dropbox.

I used to put them at the bottom of `.bashrc`, and then I put them in a file called `.bash_profile` which it sourced, but now I see that `.bashrc` no longer sources `.bashrc_local` (did it ever or did I customise this?), and I note that it sources `.bash_aliases` and `.bash_completion`.

So I've decided as it's non existent at the mo to put the stuff in `.bash_aliases`, as it seems cleanest to have my customisations in a separate file to the default.

I got scared off `.profile` as it already has stuff in it.

I realise what I'm doing works, but it seems a bit counter intuitive to be putting these things in a file called aliases when it's not all aliases.

Is this the correct place for this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where to declare environment variables?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/4667/where-to-declare-environment-variables)

Comment: Personally, if it's just one account, I use only `.bash_aliases` for aliases and `.bashrc` for the other stuff.

Answer (score 5):

Startup scripts are a bit of a maze, aren't they?

I believe that it basically works out that `.profile` is executed for login shells -- i.e., what you'd get if you login remotely -- and `.bashrc` is used for non-login shells, assuming you're using bash. `.profile` sources `.bashrc`, so in general you'd put stuff you always use in `.bashrc`, like additions to the default path and other environment settings. I believe the general convention in *nix systems and bash is to do most of the customization in `.bashrc`; I haven't seen `.bash_aliases` on Red Hat-family Linux distributions or the Unix systems I've used. I don't remember ever seeing a `.bash_local`.

The way `.bash_aliases` is sourced seems like a good model, so it might be tidier to do your customizations in another file, adding this to the end of `.bashrc`:

```
# Local customized path and environment settings, etc.
if [ -f ~/.bash_local ]; then
    . ~/.bash_local
fi
```

It can be helpful to look at `/etc/skel`, where the default user scripts are that are copied to new users' home directories, and at `/etc/profile` and `/etc/bash.bashrc`, which are system-wide defaults.

I think the underlying assumption to all of this is that the user can do as the user pleases with personal copies of `.profile`, `.bashrc`, etc., so no presumptions are made about what is or is not in them.

Comment: I don't know what's gone wrong with the formatting, but I think the meaning of the code snippet should be obvious.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect `.bashrc_local` is an invention of yours. Me too have something similar, with an expression like this in `~/.bashrc`

```
if [[ -r ~/.bashrc_local ]]; then
    . ~/.bashrc_local
fi
```

but I put in this file only customization specific to the given machine, and let the customization common to all my machines in `~/.bashrc`, synced in some way.