# How do I get Ubuntu to look somewhere for library files?

Tags: 12.04, libraries, shared-library

I have installed OpenMPI and a package called CVODE onto my Ubuntu system, which is running in a virtual machine (using VirtualBox). There was one problem which was worked around by copying some library files to `/usr/lib`. In other words, the following happened when I tried the example programs that came with CVODE:

```
$ mpirun ./cvAdvDiff_bnd 
cvAdvDiff_bnd: error while loading shared libraries: libsundials_cvode.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

$ sudo cp /home/jeff/sundials/instdir/lib/libsundials_cvode.so.1 /usr/lib/libsundials_cvode.so.1
$ mpirun cvAdvDiff_bnd
cvAdvDiff_bnd: error while loading shared libraries: libsundials_nvecserial.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

$ sudo cp /home/jeff/sundials/instdir/lib/libsundials_nvecserial.so.0 /usr/lib/libsundials_nvecserial.so.0
$ mpirun cvAdvDiff_bnd

2-D Advection-Diffusion Equation
Mesh dimensions = 10 X 5
Total system size = 50
Tolerance parameters: reltol = 0   abstol = 1e-05

At t = 0      max.norm(u) =  8.954716e+01 
At t = 0.10   max.norm(u) =  4.132889e+00   nst =   85
At t = 0.20   max.norm(u) =  1.039294e+00   nst =  103
At t = 0.30   max.norm(u) =  2.979829e-01   nst =  113
At t = 0.40   max.norm(u) =  8.765774e-02   nst =  120
At t = 0.50   max.norm(u) =  2.625637e-02   nst =  126
At t = 0.60   max.norm(u) =  7.830425e-03   nst =  130
At t = 0.70   max.norm(u) =  2.329387e-03   nst =  134
At t = 0.80   max.norm(u) =  6.953434e-04   nst =  137
At t = 0.90   max.norm(u) =  2.115983e-04   nst =  140
At t = 1.00   max.norm(u) =  6.556853e-05   nst =  142

Final Statistics:
nst = 142    nfe  = 174    nsetups = 23     nfeLS = 0      nje = 3
nni = 170    ncfn = 0      netf = 3
```

The problems finding those two files were solved by copying them to `/usr/lib`. However, there are hundreds of files in `~/sundials/instdir/lib/`.

How can I get Ubuntu to look for those files in their current location instead of copying them all to `/usr/lib/`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or `LD_PRELOAD` environment variables, documented in [`man ld.so`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/ld.so.8.html).

**Related:**

- [How do I set environment variables?](https://askubuntu.com/q/730)
- [Where to declare environment variables?](https://askubuntu.com/q/4667)

Comment: Notes: export is lowercase. :D