# Cannot set CLASSPATH

Tags: command-line, java

I'm using the command "java -cp /home/ubuntu/myapp" to set the command to the directory where mu app's classes are located. However I seem to be having no luck. The terminal simply answers by giving me a list of possible java commands - which funnily enough include "-cp". How do I get Ubuntu to take me seriously and actually do what I tell him?

Comment: could you tell me what you get in terminal "java -version"

Answer (score 1):

#### Executive Summary

`java -cp` doesn't automatically run a program in the specified classpath, it just specifies the classpath to use when running a Java program *which you must then specify in that same command.*

#### Full Explanation

`java` runs Java programs. It does not modify them or store persistent configuration about them.

The `-cp` flag does not *set* the classpath, it *specifies* a classpath to use when running a java program.

Running `java` with *only* a `-cp` flag (and its argument) is invalid syntax. You must tell `java` *what java program you want to run with that classpath*. This will run that program, once, with that classpath. It will not cause it to be run with that classpath in the future unless the classpath is specified again.

It's unclear from your question exactly what you're trying to accomplish, but I've detailed a few possibilities below.

(If you still need more information, please feel free to edit your question for clarification and comment on this answer, or if you find you have a separate question, you can ask it separately. [The manual page for the `java` command](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/java.html) may also help; please note that the name of a class or `jar` file is required. To get the manual page for the exact installed version of `java` on your machine, run `man java`.)

#### You might not have to manually set a classpath at all.

If `myapp` is a directory located in `/home/ubuntu`, which contains classes for your program, then you don't (generally) have to specify a classpath at all. In that case, just run the program (i.e., pass the name of the class that contains the program's `main` function to `java`.

For example, if the `.class` file for the class that contains your `main` method is `/home/ubuntu/myapp/launch-myapp.class`, just run:

```
java /home/ubuntu/myapp/launch-myapp
```

(Note that you don't specify the `.class` suffix, as it is implied.)

Most Java programs consist of multiple classes and often all the `.class` files are packed into a single `.jar` file. If that's the case, run `java` with the `-jar` flag and specify its full filename.

For example, if your program's classes (including the class containing `main`) is provided by the file `/home/ubuntu/myapp/myapp.jar`, just run:

```
java -jar /home/ubuntu/myapp/myapp.jar
```

Note that, to run a `.jar` file with `java -jar`, you *do* specify the `.jar` extension at the end of the filename; it is *not* taken to be implied.

#### Much less frequently, you might really want to manually specify a classpath.

To do that, you must specify the the classpath *and* also what Java program you want to run (i.e., the class that contains its `main` method).

For example, suppose you want to run `/home/bob/myapp.class` with the classpath `/home/ubuntu/myapp`. Then you would run:

```
java -cp /home/ubuntu/myapp /home/bob/myapp
```

Or if you're running `/home/bob/myapp.jar` with that classpath:

```
java -cp /home/ubuntu/myapp -jar /home/bob/myapp.jar
```

#### You might be trying to set the default classpath, to be used when running any Java program in the future (except when an alternate classpath is specified).

If that's what you're trying to do, you should set the `CLASSPATH` environment variable. See [the official documentation on that](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html) as [pointed out](https://askubuntu.com/questions/321350/cannot-set-classpath#comment408168_321350) by [karel](https://askubuntu.com/users/94914/karel).

In short, you simply make `CLASSPATH` a semicolon-delimited list of the directories you want searched automatically.

For more information on setting [environment variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable), see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4667/where-to-declare-environment-variables) and [this Ubuntu documentation wiki page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables).