# How do I display ISO time system wide?

Tags: date

I'm in United States and am trying out Ubuntu. Very frustrated because all the dates and times are in non-sensical United States format:

> Date = MM.DD.YY
>
> Time = 12 hour format

I want ISO format to display system-wide:

> Date = YYYY.MM.DD
>
> Time = 24 hour format

Is this possible while keeping other United States locale stuff like $ (dollar), language, etc?

Answer (score 2):

Partial answer.

You can set the various localization parameters on a parameter-per-parameter base using the `LC_*` environment variables. See `man locale` for a list. The one about date and time is called `LC_TIME`. You can test it by command line. For example, my default environment is en_IE:

```
$ date
Thu Nov 14 09:24:27 MST 2013
```

Seeing how date & time looks in Spanish:

```
$ LC_TIME=es_ES.UTF-8 date          
jue nov 14 09:24:25 MST 2013
```

To see all of your installed locales you should do:

```
locale -a
```

You can add support for more languages/locales to your system.

When you find a suitable locale, you can add the variable systemwide in `/etc/environment` or for your user in `~/.pam_environment` (see [Where to declare environment variables?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4667/where-to-declare-environment-variables)). For example, I have in my file:

```
$ cat ~/.pam_environment              
LANGUAGE=en
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC=en_IE.UTF-8
LC_TIME=en_IE.UTF-8
LC_MONETARY=en_IE.UTF-8
```

The answer is a partial one because I do not know if there is a locale that has the characteristics you want...