# How do I export a variable to the `sh` shell?

Tags: command-line, environment-variables, sh

Calling `export MYVAR=/path/to/whatever` from `.bashrc` obviously works for bash but not for the `sh` shell.  Unfortunately, the Matlab launcher seems hell-bent on using `sh` and not `bash`.  As such, the simplest way to export an environment variable such that it is accessible from Matlab would be to export said variable to `sh`.

**How can I persistently export an environment variable to `sh`?**

Comment: @muru I think [Where to declare environment variables?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/4667/where-to-declare-environment-variables)  is not sufficiently answer the  problem for the dash.

Comment: @A.B. yes it is. `/etc/environment` and `.pam_environment` apply everywhere.

Comment: @muru, that's not obvious to everyone, though.  This question has the merit of being explicit and narrower in scope.

Comment: @blz I don't see a narrow scope as a merit. And the solution to lack of obviousness is to make it obvious, not post a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perform the following steps in the current shell (*tested with zsh and bash*), **not** in dash:

1. Open your `.profile`:

   ```
   nano ~/.profile
   ```
2. Add this line

   ```
   ENV=$HOME/.dashrc; export ENV
   ```
3. Open `.dashrc`

   ```
   nano ~/.dashrc
   ```
4. Add this line:

   ```
   export MYVAR=/path/to/whatever
   ```
5. Finally reload `.profile`

   ```
   . ~/.profile
   ```

   or **log out and then log in again**.

**Now** start dash with:

- `sh`

  or
- `dash`

and type

```
$ echo $MYVAR
/path/to/whatever
```

Comment: I followed the above steps, then started `sh` from my current shell (fish), and typed `. ~/.profile`, but `echo $MYVAR` still returns nothing.

Comment: first `. ~/.profile`, than `sh`

Comment: I think part of the issue is that my user's default shell is fish.  Reloading `~/.profile` raises errors, which is unsurprising since fish is not fully bash-compliant.  How should I proceed?

Comment: Is logout and login an option?

Comment: Edit:  I got impatient and logged out/in.  Works like a charm.  Thanks again!