# $PATH variable env variable

Tags: 14.04, environment-variables

I am working on Ubuntu 14.04 version and I can see .profile and .bashrc under my home directory. .profile looks like this

```
# ~/.profile: executed by the command interpreter for login shells.
# This file is not read by bash(1), if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login
# exists.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files for examples.
# the files are located in the bash-doc package.

# the default umask is set in /etc/profile; for setting the umask
# for ssh logins, install and configure the libpam-umask package.
#umask 022

# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

And this is how my .bashrc file looks like

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac

# don't put duplicate lines or lines starting with space in the history.
# See bash(1) for more options
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# If set, the pattern "**" used in a pathname expansion context will
# match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.
#shopt -s globstar

# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "${debian_chroot:-}" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac

# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
#force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
    # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
    # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
    # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
    color_prompt=yes
    else
    color_prompt=
    fi
fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac

# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi

# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'

# Add an "alert" alias for long running commands.  Use like so:
#   sleep 10; alert
alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'

# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi
```

As we know when we open up the terminal(alt+control+t), it basically opens a non login shell. For that .bashrc is executed(correct me here if I am wrong) and not .profile. So I looked at .bashrc profile, but there I could not find any statement saying export PATH which would provide all the directories to be searched for.

my echo $PATH looks like this

```
/home/user/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

What I am trying to ask is, when PATH variable is not even mentioned in .bashrc, then how am I getting echo $PATH value? Where is export PATH script line??

Thanks

Comment: See `/etc/environment`, `/etc/profile`, `.sh` files in `/etc/profile.d/`, `/etc/bash.bashrc`...

Comment: And also know that an exported variable in the environment will affect child processes (so a variable that was exported when you logged in, will affect any terminal that you open).

Comment: hi muru,
So when I log in to get the desktop of the ubuntu, .profile is executed right? That already source .bashrc

Comment: When you login, `pam_env` sets environment variables from `/etc/environment` and `~/.pam_environment`. The display manager reads `/etc/profile` (and hence `.sh` files in `/etc/profile.d`) and `~/.profile`. `.profile` sources `.bashrc` *if* it is loaded by `bash`, not otherwise.

Comment: The way .profile is written in the ubuntu 14.04 , it sources .bashrc. What do you mean by if is loaded by bash??
Also is there a good document , I can rea about these files you mentioned above?

Comment: The default `.profile` checks for the existence of the `BASH_VERSION` variable before loading `.bashrc`, which only happens when it is read by `bash`. If yours doesn't, it isn't the default `.profile`. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables and http://askubuntu.com/questions/4667/where-to-declare-environment-variables, http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/813/how-to-determine-where-an-environment-variable-came-from.

Comment: @muru: Since a few months, the display manager is run under bash when sourcing `~/.profile`. Hence `~/.bashrc` gets always sourced.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Bash or the user's login shell? If not the latter, then it is a bug.

Comment: @muru: Both lightdm and gdm are now run under bash (in Ubuntu) when sourcing `~/.profile`. It's due to the fix of [bug #678421](https://launchpad.net/bugs/678421).