# How to add samtools in the PATH permanently

Tags: command-line, bash, environment-variables, bashrc, .profile

I installed samtools executables within my bin directory under home directory.
Installation works perfectly well. I am using Ubuntu 14.04 version and it has `.profile` and `.bashrc` in my home directory which looks like this which I asked in my previous post.

[previous post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/657546/path-variable-env-variable)

I want to add my `/home/user/bin` directory permanently in my `PATH` so that when I open the terminal, it automatically has samtools in the path. My .profile says to put `/home/user/bin` in the path but it is not executable.

How can I do it?

I have to run it like this after opening the terminal

```
. .profile
which samtools
/home/user/bin/samtools
```

Hope to hear from you guys

Thanks

Comment: Hi Ron,
I did this  in my .bashrc and it worked
export PATH=/path/to/dir:$PATH

but the post says .bashrc is not the right place to set env variables.
Why is that??

Comment: @user3138373 - Generally (quote): 'If you put your path in `.profile` it will be available to your complete desktop session'. Bash specific, I think the rc file is for the interactive bits, and the `profile` is for setting run time bits such as the path - see also: http://stefaanlippens.net/bashrc_and_others . This mostly explained in `man bash`

Comment: `~/.profile` adds `~/bin` to PATH automatically if it exists. You don't need to do anything.

Comment: Hi Gunnar,
You are right, .profile adds bin folder the PATH but then why my executable's in that bin folder doesn't get sourced when I open up the terminal??

Comment: Don't understand what you mean by "sourced" in this context. If you have an executable in your `~/bin` named **samtools**, you can run it from anywhere by the command `samtools`.

Comment: Btw, you need to log out and log in again after having created the `~/bin` folder.

Comment: This is my .profile file looks like
It has this for loop in it

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi
So i just made a bin folder in my home directory and place my executables in that bin folder. closed the terminal , opened them again; typed which samtools and nothing is showed. If I do . .profile, then which samtools work. HELP!!

Comment: Log out from the **session** and log in again. Just closing and reopening the terminal is not sufficient.

Comment: @user3138373 how did you install samtools?