# Wine problem: No such file or directory

Tags: wine

When I try to launch wine it returns following message:

`/usr/cyrex/.wine:
 No such file or directory`

My account name is not even cyrex, and I tried to change WINEPREFIX, but it only works temporarary, till I close terminal. Then everything restarts

Comment: What is your username? Did you change it recently? Did you try to run winecfg?

Comment: As a workaround you could [set WINEPREFIX on login](http://askubuntu.com/questions/4667/where-to-declare-environment-variables). But I do agree with Eduardo, it is more interesting to see why doesn't it work by default for you. Tell also — does `echo $WINEPREFIX` returns anything *(before you set it)*?

Answer (score -1):

It will be better if you install the latest version of wine using these commands

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
>
> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install -y wine1.7

I don't think there should be any error if you try to open wine now.Check it out though.

Comment: May I know why my post was downvoted?

Comment: I didn't do it, but I guess that was because the problem have nothing to do with Wine version. And btw, wine1.7 isn't the latest, it is wine-1.9 atm. I think it is better to do `apt-get install wine` — without the version, to get the latest.

Comment: Yeah,actually I was just giving an alternative that if wine is not working correctly why not reinstall it.And thanks for the info..@Hi-Angel