# How do I configure Juju to use Amazon Web Services (AWS)?

Tags: juju, amazon-ec2

I'd like to deploy services on AWS, how can I configure Juju to do this?

Answer (score 3):

First install Juju:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:juju/stable
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -y install juju-core
```

Do a `juju generate-config -w` to generate a config for AWS that you can customize for your needs. This will create the file `~/.juju/environments.yaml`.

Which is a sample environment configured to run with EC2 machines and S3 permanent storage.

To make this environment actually useful, you will need to tell juju about an AWS access key and secret key. To do this, you can either set the `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` [environment variables](https://askubuntu.com/questions/730/how-do-i-set-environment-variables) (as usual for other EC2 tools) or you can add access-key and secret-key options to your environments.yaml. These are already in place in the generated config, you just need to uncomment them out. For example:

```
default: sample
environments:
  sample:
    type: ec2
    access-key: YOUR-ACCESS-KEY-GOES-HERE
    secret-key: YOUR-SECRET-KEY-GOES-HERE
    control-bucket: juju-faefb490d69a41f0a3616a4808e0766b
    admin-secret: 81a1e7429e6847c4941fda7591246594
    default-series: precise
    ssl-hostname-verification: true
```

See the [EC2 provider documentation](https://juju.ubuntu.com/docs/provider-configuration-ec2.html) for more options. The S3 bucket does not need to exist already.

Note If you already have an AWS account, you can determine your access key by visiting [your account page](http://aws.amazon.com/account), clicking "Security Credentials" and then clicking "Access Credentials". You'll be taken to a table that lists your access keys and has a "show" link for each access key that will reveal the associated secret key.

And that's it, you're ready to go!

- https://juju.ubuntu.com/docs/getting-started.html
- https://juju.ubuntu.com/docs/provider-configuration-ec2.html