# q4wine: Cannot find or execute the 'wine' binary

Tags: wine

i tried to download [`q4wine`](https://github.com/brezerk/q4wine) and everything went well but when i tried to open the software it gave me this:

> Cannot find or execute the 'wine' binary. Make sure that this binary is available by search PATH variable and see also INSTALL file for application depends

Answer (score 0):

Use `sudo apt-get install wine`.

WINE is a Windows API implementation on Linux which `q4wine` depends on.

Look into [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wine_%28software%29) for more information.

If you need to set up your `$PATH`, you can set it inside `/etc/environment`. It should look like:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
```

Comment: i have it but i dosent find my wine binary D:

Comment: i cant get wine

Comment: I changed my answer, check the changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can install q4wine using:

```
sudo apt-get install q4wine
```

This may need wine, and would be installed as a dependency if not previously installed. The wine binary should be in `/usr/bin`, if it is not in your `$PATH` variable, refer to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/731/171636) to add `/usr/bin` to your `$PATH` variable.

Comment: wheres is my /usr/bin? @jobin

Comment: btw i already have installed q4 wine @jobin

Comment: @user257719: What is the output of `which wine`?