# Create an alias to a desired directory to use within the Terminal

Tags: directory, shortcuts, alias

I constantly need to type:

```
cd /home/geo/Geant4/geant4.10.00.p02-install/lib/Geant4-10.0.2
```

How do I create an alias to that directory, so I could just type:

```
cd $geant (or any other word I decide to create as the alias name)
```

It would also help me whenever I need to use `cmake` because I could use `$geant` as well in the middle of a `cmake` option.

Thanks.

Comment: uhh sorry. I'm new to ubuntu and those stuff and I didnt know that it was basically the same question

Comment: No problem! askubuntu does this automatically when I mark a question as duplicate to let you know where you find your answer. That's the beauty of it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Open your `$HOME/.bashrc` and append:

```
export GEANT=/home/geo/Geant4/geant4.10.00.p02-install/lib/Geant4-10.0.2
```

then run `source ~/.bashrc`  and now you schould be able to use it like this:

```
cd $GEANT
```

Comment: thank you sir. i have been trying with the alias command, but seems they are only to command

Comment: You are welcome!. I described the way how you can create your own environment variable (more info: http://askubuntu.com/questions/730/how-do-i-set-environment-variables). Alias do not work in this case (as far as I know).

Answer (score 1):

Just create a link in nautilus, and treat it as a normal folder. Terminal will go straight to it.

Comment: actually I dont mind the "cd" part. i care more about the cmake. i always need to do cmake -dGeant4_DIR=/home/geo/Geant4/geant4.10.00.p02-install/lib/Geant4-10.0.2 and thats a long command which i need to keep looking the full directory everytime i run the program.  I'd rather type cmake -DGeant_DIR=$geant.

Comment: I think that will work.

Comment: tried it using cmake. it gave errors when configuring =\

Comment: @Geo Can you show the errors to us?

Comment: sure. After installing Geant4, tried to run an example (B3) with the /home/geo/geant being a link to that big directory i need to use

heres the output: http://imageshack.com/a/img855/4199/dd5n.png

Comment: Tuknutx has the right idea, use that. Sorry mine was wrong...

Comment: its cool =)
your mode works with a "cd" command, but some programs (or at least geant4) had a problem reading that as a link

Comment: Yeah :) An I learnt that I could use them in terminal! :P