# Create an alias for a directory while working in virtual environment

Tags: bash

I've checked [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/486860/create-an-alias-to-a-desidred-directory-to-use-within-terminal).

But right now I'm working in a virtual env.

```
cam@cam:~$ cd Desktop/django-user3
cam@cam:~/Desktop/django-user3$ source newenv/bin/activate
(newenv)cam@cam:~/Desktop/django-user3$ cd superlists
(newenv)cam@cam:~/Desktop/django-user3/superlists$
```

Now i need to add an alias so that when i enter

```
cam@cam:~$ cd $DJANGO3
```

I need to get here.

```
(newenv)cam@cam:~/Desktop/django-user3/superlists$
```

but instead of this long path i need to see a shorter one.

Comment: So, what is it you want? An alias, or a way to make the prompt shorter?

Comment: alias with shorter prompt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To shorten the prompt, one way is to set `PROMPT_DIRTRIM`:

```
$ cd /usr/share/man/man1
/usr/share/man/man1 $ PROMPT_DIRTRIM=3
.../share/man/man1 $
```

`PROMPT_DIRTRIM`, when set, limits the number of directories shown in the prompt path, replacing earlier parts with `...`.

There are other ways, such as removing unnecessary elements from them (such as the hostname). For that you'd need to edit `PS1` in your `.bashrc`.

To create an alias, just string all your commands together. Aliasing `cd` just for this purpose isn't a very good idea. I'd use some other name, like `django3`:

```
alias django3='cd ~/Desktop/django-user3; source newenv/bin/activate; cd superlists; PROMPT_DIRTRIM=1'
```

Then you can do:

```
cam@cam:~ $ django3
(newenv)cam@cam:.../django-user3/superlists $
```

Comment: i've installed zsh.
I've seen oh-my-zsh.It displays only current directory.Can i tweak zsh so that is displays only current directory rather long paths..

Comment: @Ajay I suppose you meant tweak bash?

Comment: I've installed zsh and downloaded dot files from [github](http://git.io/.files).It has customised seetings.Now PROMPT_DIRTRIM doesn't work

Comment: @Ajay PROMPT_DIRTRIM is for bash. With zsh, find where `PROMPT` is defined, and find `%~` and insert a number, like `%2~`.

Comment: https://github.com/xero/dotfiles/tree/master/zsh/.zsh
this is the config

Comment: @Ajay I'm not going to wade through someone else's dotfiles. No, thanks.