# Create global shell command for LightTable

Tags: command-line, bash, paths

Trying to create a global command to launch lighttable (the editor) version 0.8.0

Initially I tried it the i thought easy way and moved the extracted lighttable folder to /opt and then created a symlink

```
sudo ln -s LightTable /usr/bin/Lt
```

When that didn't work I changed it to

```
sudo ln -s ./LightTable /usr/bin/Lt
```

That didn't work so I have tried to add the directory to my path and then create an alias from there.

The command to execute lighttable is

```
./Lighttable
```

so in my ~/.profile I have added

```
export LT_HOME=/opt/lighttable/ 
export PATH=$PATH:$LT_HOME
```

then I created my ~/.bash_aliases file and added

```
alias light="./LightTable"
```

I then restarted the shell and tried using the alias however it fails

```
sayth@:~$ light
bash: ./LightTable: No such file or directory
```

How can I achieve this?

**Edit**

Couldn't initial locate an answer, have now found

https://askubuntu.com/a/500698/25659

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo ln -s LightTable /usr/bin/Lt
sudo ln -s ./LightTable /usr/bin/Lt
```

Neither command does what you think it will do. In both cases, `Lt` points to the `LightTable` in the current directory *relative to itself*.

What you should do is specify the full path of the link's target:

```
sudo ln -s /opt/lighttable/LightTable /usr/bin/Lt
```

---

```
alias light="./LightTable"
```

You're still running `LightTable` from the current directory (`./`). When you provide a path, absolute or relative, to a command, then the `PATH` isn't checked. You should have run just `LightTable`, or the alias should be just:

```
alias light=LightTable
```