# Run Julia from Terminal

Tags: command-line, binary, julia-lang

I have just installed Julia 1.7.2 in my notebook (I have Ubutnu 20.04). The folder containing Julia is in Downloads. I can run julia by runing

```
$ ./Downloads/julia-1.7.2/bin/julia
```

That is, looking the executable in the folder, but I wonder how can I run Julia by simply tipping `$ julia` on terminal. I tried adding the direction to terminal but doesn't works.

Do you know how can I do it?

Comment: What did you try, exactly? Did you see the answers in [How can I make it so I can run a specific program, just by typing its name in the console?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/500694/how-can-i-make-it-so-i-can-run-a-specific-program-just-by-typing-its-name-in-th) for example?

Comment: I tried that, but when I do "source /.bashrc" it says can't found the direction

Comment: Surely you mean `source ~/.bashrc` or `source $HOME/.bashrc` .