# How to easily bump a package for a PPA?

Tags: ppa, packaging, launchpad

What's the easiest way to bump the version number for a package that shall be uploaded to a Launchpad PPA?

For instance, what I do now is that on each new release I unpack the previous `*.debian.tar.gz`, then open `debian/changelog`, copy/paste top-most entry:

```
package (1.67-1~precise~ppa1) precise; urgency=low

  * New upstream release.

 -- Name Surname <email@smth.asd>  Wed, 19 Mar 2014 22:22:03 +0200
```

Then modify `1.67` to `1.68`, and manually change date to `Tue, 03 Mar 2015`, and save file.

There surely must be a simpler way to do this...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After unpacking the `*.debian.tar.gz` file, you can use the `dch` commands to create new changelog entries. For example, `dch -i` would (probably) bump up the version to `1.67-1~precise~ppa2`. You can instead use `dch -v "1.68-1~precise~ppa1"` to specify the new version.

Note that `dch` can also take in another argument that represents the message for that changelog entry. For example, `dch -v "1.68-1~precise~ppa1" "New upstream release."`. You can append to an existing changelog entry by doing `dch -a "Another message."`.

Note that all of the above commands leave the distribution as `UNRELEASED`, signifying that it's not ready to be released. You can have `dch` mark it as released by running `dch -r --distribution precise ""` (empty message at the end).

To set your name/email combination, you can define the appropriate environment variables in `~/.bashrc`:

```
export DEBEMAIL="address@someemail.dom"
export DEBFULLNAME="Name Surname"
```

See also:

- [How do I set environment variables?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/730/how-do-i-set-environment-variables)

Comment: One issue that I notice is that `dch` will use `Geek <geek@liv-inspiron>`, instead of my usual name/email combination. How can I instruct it?

Comment: @landroni You can force them using the `DEBEMAIL` and `DEBFULLNAME` environment variables.