# Installing Cinnamon 2.6 on Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: apt, package-management, 15.04, cinnamon

There is information on the Internet ([here for example](http://ubuntuportal.com/2015/06/cinnamon-2-6.html)) about using the PPA `ppa:moorkai/cinnamon` to get Cinnamon 2.6 installed on Ubuntu 15.04.  I'm noticing that that the install fails, as it requires `libcjs0` at least 2.0.0.

If I install that package manually, attempting to install Cinnamon then results in a failure about the `cjs` package. The setup of those packages won't let me have `libcjs0` and `cjs` packages installed at the same time; each insists on the removal of the other.

I could force the install of one of them, but that seems undesirable given that I really don't know what the packages do or what they affect.

The install from `ppa:gwendal-lebihan-dev/cinnamon-nightly` does work. (Well, the *installation* works, but the desktop environment is completely unusable; something's obviously wrong because it's just broken.

Comment: What's the problem here? That a PPA from a random person doesn't work but the PPA from the developer works?

Comment: @muru well you're right of course :)  As it happens, the alleged "stable" PPA doesn't install, and while the "nightly" one does install, it is wildly unstable and completely unusable. I'll wait until the packages are directly available I guess (or until I install Mint, I guess). Thanks.

Comment: Didn't Gwendal have a stable PPA?

Comment: At any rate, consider informing the PPA maintainer (https://launchpad.net/~moorkai) that the packages are broken. Maybe he might know what went wrong with his build.

Comment: @muru I don't know; if so, I don't know what it is and I haven't found any references to it anywhere. That's kind-of what I was asking here. There's an old (2012) question on the topic, but, well, it's old.

Comment: @muru I'll notify moorkai as soon as whatever's wrong with Launchpad gets fixed (I can't log in; I get a "Bad Request" error).

Comment: Working with moorkai PPA: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2015/05/install-cinnamon-2-6-in-ubuntu-15-0414-04/

Answer (score 2):

I'm *moorkai*. I received a few e-mails with complaints about the PPA not being usable, but I really didn't expect so much users will try to install Cinnamon from my PPA ... and fail due to my sloppiness. I guess I deserve the bashing from the commenters then. I am sincerely sorry for all the inconvenience caused. I had some issues with the Launchpad system refusing my uploads, but I'll provide a (hopefully) adequate workaround. If everything goes well, the packages ought to be up in less than a few hours.

Comment: The *workaround* is the *EDIT 2* in the PPA's description.

Comment: Workaround removed. Package version bumped as suggested in [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/592322/how-to-easily-bump-a-package-for-a-ppa).

Comment: Hey don't worry about it :) I'm OK and it's really not that big of a deal.  I'm very grateful for the effort you've put into it, even though it didn't work at the time. I'm going to install Mint on another laptop to play with the environment. Thank you very much for dropping in with your answer!

Comment: Ah, okay then :). Textual communication has always been too complicated (read: vague) for me :P. Nevertheless, most of the packages are rebuilt now for Vivid and everything should be fine. Testing it right now on my build rig ... and ... it works! Just make sure you replace that Mint logo in the menu applet with a Ubuntu one ;).