# How to modify environment variable in unix?

Tags: 14.04, environment-variables

I want to modify environment variable by user given value. For example, user will give the variable to be modified and a value to put in the variable.

I tried the command:

```
set[variable[=val]]
```

Its working fine but I don't know if its right way to modify or i have to use `export` command for that purpose?

My code is :

```bsh
modify_env(){
echo "Environmental variable:"
read var
echo "Environmental value"
read value
set [var[=value]]
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I set environment variables?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/730/how-do-i-set-environment-variables)

Answer (score 0):

From `help set`:

```
set: Set or unset values of shell options and positional parameters.
```

So for the values you are entering with `set` are literally becoming positional parameters (arguments) to `set` rather than environment variables.

```bsh
$ set foo=bar 
$ echo "$foo" ##Prints nothing because it is not a variable

$ echo "$1"  ##Prints the first argument of the command "set foo=bar"
foo=bar
```

Now from `help export`:

```
export: Set export attribute for shell variables.
```

This is what you need to set a variable throughout the environment i.e. this value will be propagated to all child processes too.

```bsh
$ export foo=bar  ##setting environment variable foo having value "bar"
$ echo "$foo"  ##printing the value of "foo" in current shell
bar
$ bash -c "echo $foo" ##printing the value of "foo" in a subshell
bar
```

So, in a nutshell you need to use the `export` builtin while setting any environment variable.