# Adding to Environment Variables

Tags: environment-variables, assembler

> I need to add a folder named **"include"** and a wine executable
>   **"fasm.exe"** to Environment Variables.

The Include folder contains .inc files that are important for code execution. Although I am on Assembly, the purpose of this include folder is quite the same as that of the C include folder.

This was quite simple in Windows but I can't figure out a way to do that **permanently** in Ubuntu 17.10 .

Comment: I recommend looking into `.bashrc` files...

Comment: .bashrc is in my Home folder. What to do after that?

Comment: Add your environmental variables... For example, in the `.bashrc` file, I would have something like `folder="folder_here"`... And then after adding your variables to this file, run `source ~/.basrhc`...

Comment: I am not able to do it. Can you please post a complete way as I am new to Ubuntu

Comment: I just permanently need to add an "include" folder that has some header files like 'win32a.inc' so that I could compile my programs. Can someone help me by giving details on how to do it?

Comment: @NerdOfCode You need to `export` variables to put them in the environment. E.g. `export folder="folder_here"`

Comment: @wjandrea I see what you mean...

Comment: Are you possibly talking about adding stuff to the the already existing `PATH` environment variable? Your mentioning of an executable makes me think you are, and if so most of the discussion here so far does not address your question very well.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Consider adding a path as an environment variable. Can you help?

Comment: You'll want to read the wiki, at least the first few sections: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables

Comment: Quite a few people might me able to help, I think, but you need to provide more information about the problem, such as **why** you need to add things to the environment. As a starter you may want to let us know the full path to both the executable and that "Include" folder. Also, please read the document which @wjandrea linked to. It may help you when rewriting the question.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson So, I am an x86 Assembly Programmer. In windows when I needed to compile a program to create a portable executable I didn't need to worry about any missing '.inc' files because I added them to Environment Variables. So, I could compile my program from anywhere using fasm. I want to do the same with Ubuntu 17.10 . Add my INCLUDE folder that has '.inc' file to Environment Variables so that I could compile my programs from anywhere without worrying about missing '.inc' headers. Please sir, get back to me if you need any more details and thanks so far.

Comment: That's over my head, I'm afraid. I know there are environment variables which are useful for C compiling, but I have no idea about Assembly. But it indeed clarifies your question, and I'd advise you to edit the question and include that info. That way more people will notice your additional information.

Answer (score 2):

To give you some background, Ubuntu 17.10 uses Wayland by default, which doesn't have environment variables per se since it doesn't run a shell (more info here: [GNOME, Wayland, and environment variables](https://lwn.net/Articles/709769/)). If you're open to switching to Xorg, refer to this question: [How do I set environment variables?](https://askubuntu.com/q/730/301745) Otherwise, read on.

If the environment variables are needed for a **command-line program**, and you use Bash, you can edit your `~/.bashrc` file. Add lines like this for example:

```
export FOLDER=~/include
```

If the environment variables are needed for a **graphical program**, I think you can use this method [from the Ubuntu wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#Launching_desktop_application_with_an_environment_variable):

> #### Launching desktop application with an environment variable
>
> You can add an environment variable to an application by editing its .desktop file. For example, to run "digiKam" with the environment variable APPMENU_DISPLAY_BOTH=1, find the corresponding digikam.desktop file and add the setting of the variable, via the env command, to the entry "Exec":
>
> ```
> Exec=env APPMENU_DISPLAY_BOTH=1 digikam -caption "%c" %i
> ```

Comment: export FOLDER=~/include. My include folder is in desktop/This\ PC

Comment: How to export from this location?

Comment: @ASKArjun That's a relative path. What is the absolute path? It's not supposed to be a relative path, is it?

Comment: Absolute path:/home/fs0c13ty/Desktop/This PC/Softwares/fasmw/INCLUDE

Comment: @ASKArjun OK, then you would use `export FOLDER=~/Desktop/This PC/Softwares/fasmw/INCLUDE`

Comment: Respected sir, @wjandrea This is a scrnshot of my .bashrc https://ibb.co/j6xU7x The terminal is still unable to find INCLUDE

Comment: @ASKArjun Whoops, I missed the space. Use `export FOLDER=~/"Desktop/This PC/Softwares/fasmw/INCLUDE"`

Comment: I am so sorry for disturbing again and again but still INCLUDE is not added to Environment Variables

Comment: @ASKArjun OK, please edit your question to clarify, what environment variables do you need to set, and what should their values be?

Comment: When I was on Windows, I went to Environment Variables and added an INCLUDE folder that has .inc files that I use when I compile my programs to obtain a windows portable executable. This INCLUDE folder in ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES is essential as I can compile my programs from anywhere without worrying about missing headers. So, in Windows I just added a path.
Is there a way to do that in Linux? Thanks for the help so far :)))

Comment: @ASKArjun Welcome, but please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1015655/edit) your question to add details.